# Convert safely between uint8_t[8] & uint64_t via cast?

Tags: c, optimization, casting, memcpy, memory-alignment

The way I'm currently doing it (I'd prefer to get rid of the `memcpy` call):

```
uint64_t integer;
uint8_t string[8];
...
memcpy(&integer, &string, 8); //or swap the parameters
```

**Assuming `integer` array length to always be a multiple of 8 (64 bits total allocation)** is a straight cast possible given compiler padding / alignment concerns?

Comment: You could use an union. But why do you want to avoid `memcpy()`? No popular optimizing compiler will emit a call.

Comment: @cremno That might be a problem as padding can be present in unions. Hence my specific mention of padding / alignment concerns.

Comment: Is the `uint8_t` array properly aligned as `uint64_t` (it isn't guaranteed to be in general, but likely is)? Do you create it?

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: It's extremely unlikely there is any padding involved in such a union. If you're paranoid, you can `_Static_assert(sizeof(union) == sizeof(uint64_t), "");`.

Comment: @mafso Yes, I do create it. I could create it using `__attribute__ ((aligned (8)))` if necessary(?). I'm assuming that because such a union would be either 64, 128, 192 bits etc. that it should always be allocated on alignment boundaries under 64-bit architectures (at least Intel)... is this a safe assumption?

Comment: `integer = string[7] << 56 | string[6] << 48 | string[5] << 40 | string[4] << 32 | string[3] << 24 | string[2] << 16 | string[1] << 8 | string[0] ` (depends on endianness of course)

Comment: thanks @myaut but I'd rather avoid the endianness concerns :) hence "safely" in the question title.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: Calling `memcpy()` is the safest and optimal way. Read http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959 and its comments.

Comment: Padding cannot be present at the start of a union. All elements have the same base address (C11 6.7.2.1 16), and you know (from their specification) that a `uint8_t[8]` and `uint64_t` are the same size, so padding won't affect this. Alignment won't affect it *any more than* it would affect allocating any other aggregate containing `uint64_t` members (do you trust `malloc` for structs? then trust it here).

Comment: Thanks @Cremno, that renders the question moot, I suppose, since I would never be concerned with compilers outside of those mentioned in the post you linked. And even others would probably pull the same optimisation trick.

Comment: Thanks @Leushenko, I guess that if I had more time I would be more willing to trust but as it is I'm keener on avoiding possible errors. What I should do is better research the alignment rules to confirm what you've said there.

Comment: I think `memcpy` is both the safest and the most efficient way to do it. Most of the time it will generate no code at all, and if for any reason your byte array is not aligned, the code will still work, though more slowly.

Comment: @cremno I would be glad if you could make that an answer -- thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Myaut's bit-shifting approach doesn't have endianness concerns; the code will do the same on all platforms. The union and `memcpy` approaches depend on the platform's endianness. Or am I missing something, like the meaning of "safely", here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to avoid or replace a `memcpy()` call if you're striving for optimization. Every modern optimizing compiler won't emit a call and generate equivalent assembly code instead. Newer GCC and Clang versions even do this when no optimization related options were given. That behavior can be disabled with `-fno-builtin` by the way.

You can verify this by yourself by using the [C++ Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXATuA5gOgAsA%2BAKFElkVUznAyLNJnoDYAWAfQ2YA4MA9jA4AKFmAy9uSCALCYkMXgG1MAQwwgISXgF0AlKQDepJIrZcMijgG5TSALYIHEAA4BPEQDJh7ADSKvAFoIABeCAIAZtbs%2BnZmWAgYMFhgMXYAvqRAAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g492%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-x%20c%20-std%3Dc99%20-Wall%20-Wextra%20-Wpedantic%22%7D%5D%7D) (or locally with `-S`, of course):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t
u8tou64(uint8_t const u8[static 8]){
  uint64_t u64;
  memcpy(&u64, u8, sizeof u64);
  return u64;
}
```

For example, GCC 4.8.1 targeting x86_64 produces:

```
u8tou64:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    pop rbp
    ret
```

And with `-O3`:

```
u8tou64:
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
    ret
```

[This blog post](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) by John Regehr comes to the same conclusion (`c5()` calls `memcpy()`):

> In my opinion `c5` is the easiest code to understand out of this little
>   batch of functions because it doesn’t do the messy shifting and also
>   it is totally, completely, obviously free of complications that might
>   arise from the confusing rules for unions and strict aliasing. It
>   became my preferred idiom for type punning a few years ago when I
>   discovered that compilers could see through the `memcpy` and generate
>   the right code.

Alternatives like using a union or bitwise operations may not result in optimal (and decent looking) code or can't be used in ISO C90 or C++ (this also includes GCC's `__may_alias__` attribute which is mentioned in the comment section).