# C++ - Converting char vector elements to single uint64

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector which holds byte data (chars) received from a socket. This data holds different datatypes i want to extract. E.g. the first 8 elements (8 Bytes) of the vector are an uint64_t. Now I want to convert these first 8 Bytes to a single uint64.
A workaround I've found is:

```cpp
// recv_buffer is the vector containing the received Bytes
std::vector<uint64_t> frame_number(recv_buffer.begin(), recv_buffer.begin() + sizeof(uint64_t));
uint64_t frame_num = frame.number.at(0);
```

Is there a way to extract the data without creating a new vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert safely between uint8\_t\[8\] & uint64\_t via cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195075/convert-safely-between-uint8-t8-uint64-t-via-cast)

Comment: I found this solution working just fine ```uint64_t frame_number = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(&recv_buffer[0]);```

Answer (score 0):

This is an effective method:

C/C++:

```
uint64_t hexToUint64(char *data, int32_t offset){
    uint64_t num = 0;
    for (int32_t i = offset; i < offset + 8; i++) {
        num = (num << 8) + (data[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Java:

```
long hexToUint64(byte[] data, int offset){
    return
        ((long)data[offset++] << 56 & 0xFF00000000000000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 48 & 0xFF000000000000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 40 & 0xFF0000000000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 32 & 0xFF00000000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 24 & 0xFF000000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 16 & 0xFF0000L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] << 8 & 0xFF00L) |
        ((long)data[offset++] & 0xFFL);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function hexToUint64(data, offset) {
    let num = 0;
    let multiple = 0x100000000000000;
    for (let i = offset; i < offset + 8; i++ , multiple /= 0x100) {
        num += (data[i] & 0xFF) * multiple;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes endianness. Probably fine, but wanted to point that out just in case :)

Comment: You can use `|` instead of `+`. Also I'd use `(unsigned char)data[i]` instead of `data[i] & 0xFF`.

Answer (score 0):

One normally uses `memcpy` or similar to a properly aligned structure, and then `ntohl` to convert a number from network byte order to computer byte order. `ntohl` is not part of the C++ specification, but exists in Linux and Windows and others regardless.

```
uint64_t frame_num;
std::copy(recv_buffer.begin(), recv_buffer.begin() + sizeof(uint64_t), static_cast<char*>(&fame_num);
//or memcpy(&frame_num, recv_buffer.data(), sizeof(frame_num));
frame_num = ntohl(ntohl);
```

It is tempting to do this for a `struct` that represents an entire network header, but since C++ compilers can inject padding bytes into `structs`, and it's undefined to write to the padding, it's better to do this one primitive at a time.

Answer (score -1):

You could perform the conversion byte by byte like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char bytesArray[8];
        
    bytesArray[0] = 0x05;
    bytesArray[1] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[2] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[3] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[4] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[5] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[6] = 0x00;
    bytesArray[7] = 0x00;
    
    uint64_t intVal = 0;
    
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[7];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[6];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[5];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[4];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[3];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[2];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[1];
    intVal = (intVal << 8) + bytesArray[0];
    
    cout<<intVal;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bytesArray[8]` goes out of bounds.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest doing the following:

```
uint64_t frame_num = *((uint64_t*)recv_buffer.data());
```

You should of course first verify that the amount of data you have in `recv_buffer` is at least `sizeof(frame_num)` bytes.

Comment: and it should be aligned

Comment: @MooingDuck Even then, you'll get UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Given that `recv_buffer` is probably `char`s, it may actually sidestep the UB.  There's no guarantee that `recv_buffer.data()` is aligned though, making that moot.

Comment: @MooingDuck IIRC the `char *` strict aliasing exception works in the other direction. You can use `char *` to access an existing object, but not `T *` to access an array of `char`s.

Comment: I've always been fuzzy on the aliasing rules, but was pretty sure it was a two-way street, though had a _lot_ of requirements (alignment being a big one)

Comment: `recv_buffer` is a `std::vector<char>`. `recv_buffer.data()` is guaranteed to be contiguous. You will have no alignment issues because char is 1 byte so a vector of chars will be fully packed.